# rendered page is clipped in Chrome print preview

Tags: google-chrome, printing, rendering

I encountered an issue with Print Preview in Google Chrome that has me stumped.

Here are two different URLs, both of which retrieve the same digital certificate, but the one fetched from ‘issuer-icef.netlify.app’ is exhibiting random clipping errors (explained below), while the one fetched from ‘certificates-icef.nextid.com’ does not exhibit clipping.

- https://issuer-icef.netlify.app/certificate?id=5e1f5910-6866-4ccf-8446-5b91f927bfbe (random clipping errors)
- https://certificates-icef.nextid.com/certificate?id=5e1f5910-6866-4ccf-8446-5b91f927bfbe (does not fail)

The clipping is an intermittent problem so you may not notice it right away and this is separate from cropping of the certificate when viewed in portrait mode. In order to recreate the issue, open the certificate, click on ‘Print/PDF’ and toggle between ‘portrait’ and ‘landscape’ mode. When the print preview fails, the certificate appears to be only partially drawn or clipped. The upper left part of the certificate can be seen, but the rest of the certificate does not appear as expected.

Any idea what can cause such an issue?